# How to use joy2key in Ubuntu 14.04 with Binding of Isaac Linux?

Tags: 14.04, deb, joystick

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have encountered this strange issue with Binding of Isaac and joy2key.

The problem is, that I seem not to be able to connect joy2key and Isaac, which were installed using a .deb package from The Humble Bundle. The joy2key is properly configured and I do see the correct instructions in the terminal window, nevertheless the character does not move (works with keyboard).

Incidentally, I have an old installation of Isaac using Steam in WINE and the same configuration of joy2key works as intended.

The .deb version is installed to the /opt folder. Could this cause some access rights issues (I'm not a power-user, but maybe something with my account vs X access rights)?

This is obviously not a high priority issue, but some assistance would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. My pad would work with other games but not with Binding of Isaac. I finally chose to install AntiMicro to remap my pad so one stick matches asdw and the other the arrow keys.
This is not the best solution in my opinion but at least it works.
Here are the downloads of AntiMicro

https://github.com/Ryochan7/antimicro/releases

Be careful, in my case, one package was missing. I had to check dependencies using

```
:~$ dpkg-deb -I /path/to/antimicro_2.14-1.bpo70.1_amd64.deb
```

I installed the missing packages with synaptic then the antimicro .deb file

```
:~$ dpkg -i /path/to/antimicro_2.14-1.bpo70.1_amd64.deb
```

Hope it helps